# ¿Cómo sustituir variables a partir de una lista en python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el cual, hago un recorrido de una carpeta principal y a su vez su sub-carpetas, abro los archivos "*.txt" que hay dentro de cada sub-carpeta y los leo y almaceno en variables asi como se muestra en el resultado de abajo

```
LXC  = "20"
FXC  = "21"
RXC  = "22"
DXC  = "23"

codigos = [LXC,FXC,RXC,DXC]

paths = "/Documents/data/archives/2016/"
listado = glob(join(paths,'*'))

for archivos in listado:
    tmp = os.path.split(archivos)
    pth = tmp[0]
    FolderPth = os.path.basename(tmp[1])
    trayectoria = archivos + "/"
    try:
        os.chdir(trayectoria)
        print '========================================================='
        print "estamos en el Folder ==>",FolderPth
        path = os.getcwd()
        for filesPath in os.listdir(path):
            isFolder = trayectoria + filesPath

            if os.path.isdir(isFolder):
                print '================'
                print "Nos encontramos en el Sub-folder==>",filesPath
                os.chdir(isFolder)
                rutaisFolder = os.getcwd() + "/"
                print rutaisFolder
                for folders in os.listdir(rutaisFolder):
                    if folders.endswith(".txt"):
                       archivoDat = isFolder + "/" + folders
                       f=open(archivoDat)
                       lines=f.readlines()

                        fname = lines[8]
                        filename = fname[41:63]

                        m = re.search("\_", filename)
                        empieza = m.start()
                        station = filename[0:empieza]

                        hrsamp = lines[67]
                        hours = hrsamp[41:49]

                        yr = filename[8:12] 
                        month = filename[6:8] 
                        day = filename[4:6] 
                        fecha = yr + '-' + month + '-' + day

                        print "Codigo",station
                        print "Fecha",fecha
                        print "Hora",hours


     except:
         print 'error'
```

Me da el siguiente resultado:

```
=========================================================
estamos en el Folder ==> PEC_20160209
================
Nos encontramos en el Sub-folder==> LXC_8934
/Documents/data/archives/2016/PEC_20160209/LXC_8934/

Codigo LXC
Fecha 2016-02-09
Hora 06:08:09
================
Nos encontramos en el Sub-folder==> RXC_8934
/Documents/data/archives/2016/PEC_20160209/RXC_8934/

Codigo RXC
Fecha 2016-02-09
Hora 07:10:18
```

La idea es que como se ve en el resultado anterior en el resultado de ***codigo*** me sale el nombre.

Como puedo hacer para que en vez que me aparezca el ***codigo*** de nombre aparezca en numero como los tengo declarados en el principio del codigo.

***¿Como puedo hacerle para obtener este resultado?***

```
=========================================================
estamos en el Folder ==> PEC_20160209
================
Nos encontramos en el Sub-folder==> LXC_8934
/Documents/data/archives/2016/PEC_20160209/LXC_8934/

Codigo 20
Fecha 2016-02-09
Hora 06:08:09
```

Comment: Hola, ¿de dónde sale la variable `station`? No la veo por ningún lado en tu código.

Comment: @César error mio, habia puesto `code`, en vez de `station` ya lo modifique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución es mapear tus códigos en un diccionario:

```
station_to_codigos = {
    'LXC': 20,
    'FXC': 21,
    'RXC': 22,
    'DXC': 23
    # más códigos
}
```

Y cuando quieras imprimirlo:

```
print station_to_codigos.get(station, 'Desconocido')
```

Si `station` no está contenido dentro del diccionario (tal vez un `station` que no hayas considerado), simplemente se mostrará el código como `Desconocido`.

Recuerda que el método `dict.get()` puedes usarlo para evitar errors del tipo `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1):

Haz que `codigos` sea un diccionario en el que la clave sean los posibles resultados de `station` y el valor el código a imprimir:

```
codigos = {'LXC': "20", 'FXC': "21", 'RXC': "22", 'DXC': "23"}
```

Al imprimer haces simplemente:

```
print "Codigo", codigos[station]
```

Esto generará un error si algún valor de `station` no está en el diccionario, si eso puede pasar usa un condicional (o el método `get()` como indica César):

```
print "Codigo:", codigos[station] if station in codigos else 'No encontrado'
```

Answer (score 0):

si lees un .txt, verifica que posición tiene los registros guardados, parece, que donde debería estar el código esta esta valor de descripción.